# Uniqueness of subspaces dual-basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, dual-spaces

Consider the vector-space $\mathbb{R}^3$. Now think of an arbitrary 1D-subspace of this vectorspace, lets say e.g. the subspace spanned by the basis vector $(1,1,0)^T$. This is a finite vector-space again - meaning it has a dual-basis with $b^{\ast}_i(b_j) = \delta_{ij}$, where $b^{\ast}_i$ is a basis of the dual-space and $b_j$ is the corresponding basis of the vector-space.

I always thought for a given basis the corresponding basis of the dual-space that fulfills the above property was unique. Now if we consider mentioned subspace, the dual-space basises that fulfill this property are (e.g. $(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0.5,0.5,0)$ etc.) and therefore not unique. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to state things more carefully.

> > **True Fact.** If $V$ is a finite-dimensional inner-product space and $B$ is a basis for $V$ then $V$ contains a unique dual basis to $B$.

The dual basis is only unique *if* it's  assumed to be contained in $V$. In the example you give, the relevant $V$ is the one-dimensional subspace. Of the three supposed dual bases you give,  only one of them is contained in $V$.

**Edit.** That was assuming for convenience we have an inner-product space. Supposing $V$ is just a vector space, let $V'$ bbe the dual:

> **True Fact 2.** If $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space with basis $B$ then $V'$ contains a unique dual basis to $B$.

Why is the example you give not a counterexample? Here $V$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$, as above. Now an element of $\Bbb R^3$ is not literally an element of $V'$. An element of $\Bbb R^3$ *defines* an element of $V'$ in a natural way, but the three vectors you mention all define the *same* element of $V'$. So you've only mentioned one element of $V'$, not contradicting uniqueness.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I can't quite close this topic yet. Since I can view vectors in the dual space as linearforms, I don't need my vector space to have an inner-product defined. Furthermore I could choose as a dual basis e.g. ( 0.5 , 0.5 , 0 )  and  ( 0.25 , 0.75 , 0 )  which would destroy the uniqueness again.

Comment: Whether we say it's an inner product space or we talk about linear forms really doesn't matter. The space you're talking about has dimension $1$. Hence the dual basis consists of exactly one vector - that pair of vectors you mention is certainly not a dual basis.

Comment: Oh. You should note that if $V$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ then a vector in $\Bbb R^3$ is not a linear functional on $V$. Elements of $\Bbb R^3$ define linear functionals on $V$ in a natural way, but the mapping is not one-to-one. Inn particular, if $V$ is the span of $(1,1,0)^T$ then the two vectors you name correspond to the same linear functional on $V$.

Comment: Hm, this confuses me a bit. I can represent the linear forms on $\mathbb{R}^3$ as $(1 \times 3)$-Matrices, can't I? But representing the linear forms as matrices would mean that (as in all matrices) changing the matrices entries defines a different map. Am I lacking some essential understanding here?

Comment: Yes, you can represent forms on $\Bbb R^3$ as matrices,, as you say. That's irrelevant here, because we're not talking about (a dual basis for) a basis of $\Bbb R^3$, we're talkiing about a dual basis for a certain basis for that subspace $V$. And you cannot represent forms on $V$ as matrices (or rather you can, but the representation is not unique - as in the edit above, the three vectors at the bottom all represent the same element of $V'$).

Comment: Ok, so in this case what made me think that this basis is not unique is the explicit representation that I favoured but which is not applicable? Thank you for your effort.

Comment: Precisely......